# Does Serilog Sinks Redis support netcore 1.x?

Tags: .net, redis, serilog

We're developing support for logging to Redis and I have two dotnet webapi projects where we write to Redis.List.

In the first project (dotnet 2.1.101) we write to a key and that works fine. It shows up in redis-commander and docker logging.

```
redis-commander    | loading key ".NET Web Api" from "redis:6379:0"
redis-commander    | loading keys by prefix ""
```

In the second project (dotnet 1.1.5), we just see

```
redis-commander    | loading keys by prefix ""
redis-commander    | found 1 keys for ""
```

Is this a known issue with dotnet 1.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I can answer my own question. I've been able to write a key to our Redis.List sink using a Netcore 1.x WebAPI project.

So, yes, Serilog.Sinks.Redis does support Netcore 1.x. Something else in our production build must be interfering with this.

Guess I need to ask a different question. :)

Later, after opening an [issue](https://github.com/dburriss/serilog-sinks-redis/issues/19#issuecomment-418194308) on this I got my answer.

It turns out that the test projects I created to test were not NET Core 1.x, but NET Core 2. So we still had the problem in our app.

The actual issue was using a hostname on my *nix platform. Changing to a static IP address allowed me to Write to the Redis Server. 
See github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8768 for more about the limitation in NET Core 1